# How to save list data in SharedPreferences flutter

Tags: flutter

I make data connection with database to bring a list of data such as the following code:

```
  var listDATA = [];
  Future listDATAs() async {
    api = '*************';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(api));

    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (responsebody.length >0){

      for (int i = 0; i < responsebody.length; i++) {
        listDATA.add(responsebody[i]['name']+ ':' + responsebody[i]['image'].toString());

      }

      return responsebody;
    }else{


    }
  }
```

How can I store listDATA in Shared Preferences I need to save name and image ? Then recall it to display after storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's preferred not to store non-primitive data types in SharedPreferences as it supports only primitive data types by default. But still there is a way to do it.

you can store the response body of your API call without decoding JSON to a `String` value.

```dart
// Obtain shared preferences.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
// Save an String value to 'response' key.
await prefs.setString('response', response.body);
```

if you have response types of List, you can use `setStringList` method

```dart
await prefs.setStringList('items', <String>['Earth', 'Moon', 'Sun']);
```

Comment: Hi bro / I make it like that /    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('response', responsebody);

    var myData = prefs.getString('response');
    String token = jsonDecode(myData!);
    print(token);  / and I get this error / [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Comment: Please make sure to not decode response. It means you must not use `jsonDecode` before storing the values.

Comment: Hello brother / yes that works fine but now if I want to use this list that I have stored like this and show it for example in the listview can I do that? I apologize but I am not a professional

Comment: You can get that list from `SharedPreference` and then use `jsonDecode` then it will be converted to List<dynamic>

Comment: Thank you brother, I will try it and if I don't succeed, I will ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

in this way you can store list value in shared preference

```
static setListValue(String key, List< ProductsModel > value) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString(key, jsonEncode(value.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList()));
}
```

her I make a standard method to store list values from any class by calling

```
setListValue('store_list', listData);
```

after that, you have to make a method for getting this list value

```
//getListValue
static Future<List<ProductsModel>?> getListValue(String key) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final dataMap = jsonDecode(prefs.getString(key) ?? '[]') as 
List<dynamic>;

return dataMap.map<ProductsModel>((item) {
  return ProductsModel.fromJson(item);
}).toList();
}
```

after that, you can call this method like this

```
var listValue = await SPUtils.getListValue('store_list');
```

Answer (score 1):

// for saving the list in shared preferences

`final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`
`prefs.setString("list",jsonEncode(listDATA));`

// for getting the list from shared preferences

`final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

`List listDATA = jsonDecode(prefs.get("list"));`

Answer (score 1):

You can follow those steps.

1. convert your object to map with `toMap()` method.
2. encode your map to string with `encode()` method.
   Save the string to shared preferences.

final SharedPreferences prefs = `await` `SharedPreferences`.`getInstance`();

`await` prefs.`setString`('key', encodedData);

// Fetch and decode data

`final` `String` musicsString = `await` prefs.`getString`('musics_key');

Example :

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {  
 final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

final String encodedData = Music.encode([
Music(id: 1, ...),
Music(id: 2, ...),
Music(id: 3, ...),
]);

```
  await prefs.setString('musics_key', encodedData);

  // Fetch and decode data   final String musicsString = await prefs.getString('musics_key');

  final List<Music> musics = Music.decode(musicsString); }

class Music {
```

final int id;
final String name,
size,
rating,
duration, img;   bool favorite;

```
  Music({
    this.id,
    this.rating,
    this.size,
    this.duration,
    this.name,
    this.img,
    this.favorite,   });

  factory Music.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return Music(
      id: jsonData['id'],
      rating: jsonData['rating'],
      size: jsonData['size'],
      duration: jsonData['duration'],
      name: jsonData['name'],
      img: jsonData['img'],
      favorite: false,
    );   }

  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(Music music) => {
        'id': music.id,
        'rating': music.rating,
        'size': music.size,
        'duration': music.duration,
        'name': music.name,
        'img': music.img,
        'favorite': music.favorite,
      };

  static String encode(List<Music> musics) => json.encode(
        musics
            .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((music) => Music.toMap(music))
            .toList(),
      );

  static List<Music> decode(String musics) =>
      (json.decode(musics) as List<dynamic>)
          .map<Music>((item) => Music.fromJson(item))
          .toList(); }
```